# How to add a variable to a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, organization

I want to add on to my current dictionary without hard-coding. I want to distinguish between stores by adding on -A and -B based on the station someone is working in.

```
a_dict = {'A': [['LA', 'Sallys', 'Associate '], ['Hollywood', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'], ['Compton', 'Sally', 'Shelves']],'B': [['SAC', 'Sallys', 'Associate '], ['Townsland', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'], ['Compton', 'Tiffanys', 'Shelves']]}
    b_dict = {'Site':"", 'Store':"", 'Station':""}
    for key in a_dict:
        b_dict.update(a_dict) 
        #print(b_dict[key[0]])
        #print(value[0])
        output = [
    {'Site':val[0][0], 'Store':val[1][1], 'Station':val[2]}
    for vals in a_dict.values()
    for val in vals
    ]
        
        print(output)
```

The code currently prints out this:

```
[{'Site': 'L', 'Store': 'a', 'Station': 'Associate '}, {'Site': 'H', 'Store': 'o', 'Station': 'Shelf'}, {'Site': 'C', 'Store': 'a', 'Station': 'Shelves'}, {'Site': 'S', 'Store': 'a', 'Station': 'Associate '}, {'Site': 'T', 'Store': 'o', 'Station': 'Shelf'}, {'Site': 'C', 'Store': 'i', 'Station': 'Shelves'}]
[{'Site': 'L', 'Store': 'a', 'Station': 'Associate '}, {'Site': 'H', 'Store': 'o', 'Station': 'Shelf'}, {'Site': 'C', 'Store': 'a', 'Station': 'Shelves'}, {'Site': 'S', 'Store': 'a', 'Station': 'Associate '}, {'Site': 'T', 'Store': 'o', 'Station': 'Shelf'}, {'Site': 'C', 'Store': 'i', 'Station': 'Shelves'}]
```

But I want it to print out this:

```
[{'Site': 'L', 'Store': 'a-A', 'Station': 'Associate '}, {'Site': 'H', 'Store': 'o-B', 'Station': 'Shelf'}, {'Site': 'C', 'Store': 'a-B', 'Station': 'Shelves'}, {'Site': 'S', 'Store': 'a-A', 'Station': 'Associate '}, {'Site': 'T', 'Store': 'o-B', 'Station': 'Shelf'}, {'Site': 'C', 'Store': 'i-B', 'Station': 'Shelves'}]
[{'Site': 'L', 'Store': 'a-A', 'Station': 'Associate '}, {'Site': 'H', 'Store': 'o-B', 'Station': 'Shelf'}, {'Site': 'C', 'Store': 'a-B', 'Station': 'Shelves'}, {'Site': 'S', 'Store': 'a-A', 'Station': 'Associate '}, {'Site': 'T', 'Store': 'o-B', 'Station': 'Shelf'}, {'Site': 'C', 'Store': 'i-B', 'Station': 'Shelves'}]
```

So like if the associate is shelf or shelves than the store would be -B if not the store should be -A.

Comment: Please post the code that is giving you trouble.  You already described this as a straightforward `if` and string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
a_dict = {'A': [['LA', 'Sallys', 'Associate '], ['Hollywood', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'], ['Compton', 'Sally', 'Shelves']],'B': [['SAC', 'Sallys', 'Associate '], ['Townsland', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'], ['Compton', 'Tiffanys', 'Shelves']]}
b_dict = {'Site':"", 'Store':"", 'Station':""}
for key in a_dict:
    b_dict.update(a_dict) 
    #print(b_dict[key[0]])
    #print(value[0])
    output = [
{'Site':val[0][0], 'Store':val[1][1], 'Station':val[2]}
for vals in a_dict.values()
for val in vals
]
    for x in output:
        if x["Station"] in ("Shelf","Shelves"):
            x["Store"] += "-B"
        else:
            x["Store"] += "-A"
    print(output)
```

You said what you needed to do in the last line of your question.